Does "We will be provided with the laptops" sound unusal to native speakers?
Consider the phrase my friend used while talking to a colleague

I was told we will be provided with the laptop.

I'd rather say,

I was told we will be given the laptop.

Does the phrase "provided with" sound unusual to the native speakers?

As per usual it depends on the circumstances. If several people will need a laptop each to do a particular task,  you can say "we will be provided with laptops" or "laptops will be provided". If only one computer is involved, "we will be provided with a laptop".

There is nothing wrong with "we will be provided with" or "we will be given".  Both of these are more or less interchangeable.  The problem here is with your choice of the definite article "the".  If it's not a specific laptop, then you either have to say "with laptops" or "a latop".

Provided with suggests it will be lent to us; Given suggests  (strongly, though not exclusively) that it and its legal ownership will be transferred to us.

The laptop sounds odd... does your company/school only have a single one?

To add to James K's point, "the laptop" refers to a particular laptop. If your friend and their colleague work in IT and were planning on installing software on someone's laptop,  your friend might say "I thought we were going to be provided with the laptop" -- that someone would bring it to the IT area. Maybe now they have to devise some mechanism that would enable the software to be installed automatically via download the next time that user logs into the network.  Absent that or a similar scenario, "the" is the wrong determiner.

a laptop, a, not the.

why the downvote?

@JamesK - 'the' is not necessarily odd, depending on the context. Consider responding to job posting: "A laptop will be required for this work." The applicant asks 'Who will supply the laptop?'. Respondent answers 'You will be given the laptop'. Applicant relates the entire exchange to a friend saying 'They told me I will be given the laptop.' "The' is entirely appropriate.

@Lambie - see my comment t JamesK. 'The' can be perfectly appropriate.

@Vector the is grammatical but not general like this: I got a new job and the employer said he would provide me with a laptop. So, in a contextless situation, like in Max's question, a is more likely than the.

@Vector  I find that exchange odd.  It would be better: "Who will supply the laptop?"  Response "You'll be given a laptop".

Does the phrase provided with sound unusual to the native speakers?
No, it does not sound unusual. It is entirely common, acceptable vernacular English.
Note however, that given may have a slightly different implication than provided with. In a business context,provided with often implies that the laptop is only on loan for a particular use or duration of time. An employer mightprovide an employee with a laptop exclusively for work use, or for their term of employment. I.e. the laptop is made available for use.
Given a laptop might also mean given with such restrictions, if the restrictions were implicit from the context of the conversation, but provided with a laptop more strongly implies such restrictions. Given a laptop might be construed as an unconditional gift. In a business context, provided withis more appropriate than given.
Cambridge Dictionary - provide | BUSINESS ENGLISH

to give something to a person, company, or organization, or to make
it available for them to use


Please don't use code formatting other than for actual computer source code. Either or both of quotation marks and italics would be appropriate here.


I just got a new job and the employer told me I would be given a laptop. The laptop is brand new.

I just got a new and a new laptop.

I just got a job and the laptop they provided to me is an older model.

I just got a job and the laptop they provided me with is an older model.


OR gave me
Both a and the are grammatical. The difference is context. "the" is always specific.
provide someone with something
OR
provide something to someone
OR
to give someone something

What does the following mean to you?... Irrelevant, since the question was about choosing between given and provided with. (Both choices used the, which is entirely appropriate in certain contexts)

This does not answer the question, which was clearly stated: Does the phrase "provided with" sound unusual to native speakers, or is 'given' a better choice.  The question does not deal at all with usage of 'a' and 'the'.
